# How can I decode a JWT token which I received a REST API in Swift?

Tags: swift, rest, jwt, token

So I have two functions - one which authenticates the user so he can log in and returns a JWT token which should be verified by the second function in order to see whether the user is logged in or not and return the userID of the user by decoding the token.

My first function works and provides a JWT token but I don't know how to make the second one. How can I do that?

Here is my JWT token:

> "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiJCb2JWb2VyIiwic3ViIjoiMCIsImV4cCI6MTU4MDY4NjAwNywiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiVVNFUiJdfQ.mrfHVMNIJUssHSNn6tJ-AVVlkX6u79kp4sAQjBCu9E0"

I need to get a userID which is an Int. The veryfyToken functions returns either the userID or nil.

Some code:

```
func verifyToken (to:String, completion: @escaping (Int?)->()) { 

 let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8083/verifyToken")!
     let json: [String: String] = ["token":to]
     let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json as Any)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"


    request.httpBody = jsonData
    print("HTTPBODY:::",request.httpBody as Any)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a library to verify and decode your tokens.
The [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) site list trusted libraries for all platforms including Swift.

As of today, the listed library are:

- https://github.com/kylef/JSONWebToken.swift  <= most used
- https://github.com/vapor/jwt
- https://github.com/Wstunes/SwiftyJWT
- https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-JWT <= most compatible

If you go with JSONWebToken, the code to get the claims would look like this:

```
do {
  let claims: ClaimSet = try JWT.decode("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.e30.2_8pWJfyPup0YwOXK7g9Dn0cF1E3pdn299t4hSeJy5w", algorithm: .hs256("secret".data(using: .utf8)!))
  print(claims)
} catch {
  print("Failed to decode JWT: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a library?

Comment: You could look at the library's code to see how they are doing it, but when it comes to security, you should probably stick with libraries.

Comment: @temerot Decoding is pretty easy, there are 3 base64url encoded string connected by a `.`. The second part is the payload. So base64url decode the second part and you get a JSON containing the data.